# Couldn't start client Java Language Server

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Whenever I open Visual Studio Code (on Windows10), the message pops up in the bottom right corner. So does reopening a Java workspace. But all my plugins are updated to the latest version. Strangely, I restarted the Java Language Service without problems (using the command). After the error, I open the java plugin log and there is the following:

[image: VS Code error message]

```
{
  message: 'Removing workspace storage folder : c:/Users/77503/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/workspaceStorage/e30a982be03c6df4f9a4ba5f0771b0ff/redhat.java',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2024-03-24 11:46:42.075'
}
{
  message: "Use the JDK from 'java.jdt.ls.java.home' setting as the initial default project JDK.",
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2024-03-24 11:46:42.502'
}
{
  message: 'Starting Java server with: g:\\jdk-17.0.3+7\\bin\\java --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED -Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1 -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 -Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product -Djava.import.generatesMetadataFilesAtProjectRoot=false -DDetectVMInstallationsJob.disabled=true -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xmx1G -Xms100m -Xlog:disable -javaagent:c:\\Users\\77503\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.28.1-win32-x64\\lombok\\lombok-1.18.31.jar -jar c:\\Users\\77503\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.28.1-win32-x64\\server\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.700.v20231214-2017.jar -configuration c:\\Users\\77503\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\redhat.java\\1.28.1\\config_ss_win -data c:\\Users\\77503\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\9ded0751c8412d1c39036a35d1ca6505\\redhat.java\\ss_ws',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2024-03-24 11:46:42.719'
}
{
  message: 'Starting Java server with: g:\\jdk-17.0.3+7\\bin\\java --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED -Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1 -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 -Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product -Djava.import.generatesMetadataFilesAtProjectRoot=false -DDetectVMInstallationsJob.disabled=true -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xmx1G -Xms100m -Xlog:disable -javaagent:c:\\Users\\77503\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.28.1-win32-x64\\lombok\\lombok-1.18.31.jar -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=c:\\Users\\77503\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\9ded0751c8412d1c39036a35d1ca6505\\redhat.java -Daether.dependencyCollector.impl=bf -jar c:\\Users\\77503\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.28.1-win32-x64\\server\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.700.v20231214-2017.jar -configuration c:\\Users\\77503\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\redhat.java\\1.28.1\\config_win -data c:\\Users\\77503\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\9ded0751c8412d1c39036a35d1ca6505\\redhat.java\\jdt_ws',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2024-03-24 11:46:43.318'
}
{
  message: 'WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.incubator.vector\r\n',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2024-03-24 11:46:43.909'
}
{
  message: 'WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.incubator.foreign\r\n',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2024-03-24 11:46:43.917'
}
{
  message: '3月 24, 2024 11:46:52 上午 org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log\r\n' +
    '信息: Registered provider ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer of service jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer in bundle ch.qos.logback.classic\r\n',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2024-03-24 11:46:52.603'
}
{
  message: '3月 24, 2024 11:46:52 上午 org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log\r\n' +
    '信息: Registered provider ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider of service org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider in bundle ch.qos.logback.classic\r\n',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2024-03-24 11:46:52.612'
}
```

Reinstalling vscode did not solve the problem. Deleting all configuration files did not solve the problem. Is there an error somewhere?

In fact, I've already made that clear in the question column. Although restart client Java Language Server can solve this problem, I still want it to work as soon as vscode opens, without having to reboot and without reporting errors.

Comment: Do you have this set up? `"java.jdt.ls.java.home"`

Comment: yes.Here's my configuration.
"java.home": "G:\\jdk-17.0.3+7",
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "G:\\jdk-17.0.3+7",